# Handling Window Movement after setting GWL_STYLE to 0

Tags: windows, winapi, window, wndproc

i want to have a border and title less window so i do     SetWindowLongPtrW( window_handle, GWL_STYLE, 0 );

After that i can't move my Window so in my WndProc i do

```
if( message == WM_NCHITTEST ) {
        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect( hwnd, &rc );
        MapWindowPoints( hwnd, GetParent( hwnd ), (LPPOINT)&rc, 2 );

        int mouseX = LOWORD( lParam ) - rc.left;
        int mouseY = HIWORD( lParam ) - rc.top;
        POINT p;
        p.x = mouseX;
        p.y = mouseY;

        return PtInRect( &rc, p ) ? HTCAPTION : DefWindowProc( hwnd, message, wParam, lParam );
}
```

It works, the first time i move the window. After i once stop clicking with the mouse it won't move again :/

Comment: Compare your code to an [already existing implementation](https://github.com/melak47/BorderlessWindow).

Answer (score 1):

`SetWindowLongPtrW( window_handle, GWL_STYLE, 0 );` will hide the window, assuming it doesn't cause more serious problems. Use `GetWindowLongPtr` and combine that with valid window styles, or hide the window using `ShowWindow`

The error you have described is unrelated. You are attempting to find the screen coordinates of the window using `GetClientRect` and `MapWindowPoints`. The result will not be exact because the window may have borders and title bar.

Use `GetWindowRect` instead. This will give you screen coordinates of the window.

You can compare that with the mouse position `LOWORD(lParam)` and `HIWORD(lParam)`. This is already screen coordinates. This code will move the screen every where the mouse lands in window:

```
RECT rc;
GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rc);
int mouseX = LOWORD(lparam);
int mouseY = HIWORD(lparam);
```

Don't subtract `rc.left` and `rc.top` from mouse position. That would convert the coordinates in client coordinates (roughly). Your code may work when window is on top-left corner of the screen, but it won't work later when window is moved.

Use `ScreenToClient` if you wish to work in client window coordinates.